# cannot display dynamic image with primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, graphicimage

I want to display a dynamic photo with 
I'm storing the content of the image as a blob in the database , the content type in the photo entity is a byte array (byte[]) .
I tried two diffrent ways but both was useless.

1)

```
 public StreamedContent getImage() throws IOException {
  byte[] img=photo.getContent();
 InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(img);
 StreamedContent  image = new DefaultStreamedContent(in,"image/jpeg");
  return image;
}
```

2)

```
public StreamedContent getImage() throws IOException {
  byte[] img=photo.getContent();
 InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(img);
 BufferedImage bufferedImg = ImageIO.read(in);
 ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 ImageIO.write(bufferedImg, "jpeg", os);

 StreamedContent   image = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()),"image/jpeg");

  return image;
}
```

and in the view page :

```
  <p:graphicImage value="#{controller.image}"/>
```

So could someone help me to make it work !!

Comment: What scope is the backing bean? If it's view scoped this won't work.

Comment: @siebz0r no the bean scope is session

Comment: Any other solutions plz , i tried with image url also it does not work  because images has to be under /resources/images or directly under /images and my images are located in other path when uploaded :(

Answer (score 2):

You first must retrieve the blob from the database.

```
public StreamedContent getImage() throws SQLException {
    Blob imgBlob;
    try
    {
     //Select the blob from your database here. Use a PreparedStatement (I'll call it stmt here) for this.
     ...
     ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
     res.next();
     imgBlob = res.getBlob("columnName");
    }
    catch(SQLException e){ throw e; }
    byte[] img=imgBlob.getBytes(1, imgBlob.length()); //Get the blob as a byte array
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(img);
    StreamedContent  image = new DefaultStreamedContent(in,"image/jpeg");
    return image;
}
```

[More info about the Blob class.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html)

Comment: ' Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sensordb","root","root");
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT content FROM photo    where idPhoto="+id);
    rs.next();
    InputStream binaryStream = rs.getBinaryStream("content"); '

Comment: That's the problem, you're trying with `getBinaryStream`. Try with `getBlob` instead.

Comment: I tried with getBlob also and it didnt work , i tried all possibilies but i's useless :(

Comment: i dont get errors but the photo is not displayed (an empty small icon is only displayed instead of the photo)

Comment: Do the query manually in mySQL and see what results you're getting. Also, is `id` setted correctly?

Comment: yes i already did it and the query is returning the content of the image  correctly so i have problem in the display :(

Comment: Hi @Carlos. `DefaultStreamedContent(InputStream stream, String contentType)` is deprecated.